# Is assurity a proper English word

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

I found that `assurity` is not available in the online https://dictionary.cambridge.org/
But I did find it on https://www.urbandictionary.com/ . Is this proper English words
Do Americans or Canadians use it? I have heard this word from non-native English speakers

Comment: 'Assurity' isn't in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/) either (Oxford Dictionary) but, I found it [here](https://www.definitions.net/definition/assurity) – a Caribbean dialect word meaning : firm promise.

Comment: Urban Dictionary is a crowdsourced online dictionary for slang words and phrases, and contains many words which will not be found in standard dictionaries.

Comment: As Weather Vane says Assurity is a Caribbean dialect word. However, there are some companies that use it in their corporate name such as Assurity Consulting who are a long way from the Caribbean  being in West Sussex UK. There are others. Maybe where you've seen it it should have been **assurance** which is used in a very similar way in BrE. Caribbean : "You have my **assurity** that I will pay you tomorrow"  means the same as BrE : "You have my **assurance** I will pay you tomorrow". In other words, a firm promise of payment.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not sure that one anonymous post on some website is proof enough. Some should pick up a phone and call, say, the Jamaican Consulate or embassy in their area. That's how to do this sort of thing. Or Trinidad and Tobago. The Caribbean is very diversified.

Comment: @Lambie then it's a good thing that I didn't post an answer. It's still not a "proper English word." The Lexico link is broken but it's not in Cambridge dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The word normally used is 'surety', which is probably where it evolved from in the Caribbean, (from 'a surety'). But used to mean 'being sure' is an archaic or obsolete use of the term now; though it can still be found in places like the KJ bible, (in Job 13 for instance).

Comment: This was what I was going to say. "A surety" would be a common usage in finance, possibly referring to a surety bond, or the person or organization backing a surety bond (called, confusingly "a surety").